# Does GWT support inclusion of stylesheet during GWTTestCase?

Tags: gwt, junit, gwttestcase

I have some simple GWT client code that I would like to test using `GWTTestCase` and GWTTestSuite.

However, those tests require the use of some `CSS stylesheet` (only needed for the tests).

My first attempt was :

1. Define a `ClientBundle` that provide the CSS file used for tests.
2. in my `gwtSetUp()`, call the `ensureInjected() method to add the CSS file before my tests get called
3. Test if the CSS style was applied to a particular element in the DOM, for example

code:

```java
assertEquals("blue", element.getStyle().getBorderColor());
```

**I got no errors, but this not seems to work.**

Looking throught the logs of the Console (during the Junit test) I found this :

> Initializing ResourceGenerator 
>            Finding operable CssResource subtypes
>            Computing CSS class replacements
>         Preparing method css
>            Finding resources
>            Parsing CSS stylesheet file:/D:/Workspace/libraries/gwt-text/gwt-text/src/test/java/com/t/i/client/CSSDecorationTest.css
>            Scanning CSS for requirements
>         Creating fields
>         Creating assignment for css()
>            Creating image sprite classes
>            Replacing property-based @if blocks
>            Replacing CSS class names
>            Performing substitution in node border-color : ..... ;

My css file simple contains :

```css
.d {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

### EDIT

Please see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10575244/921244

This was the wrong approach as getStyle do not provide the CSS computed style. Too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to do anything special with your CSS (i.e. it's a simple CSS, not a `CssResource`), then you could simply create a GWT module (`gwt.xml` file) dedicated for your tests (make it `<inherits>` your *module-under-test* and have your `GWTTestCase`'s `getModuleName` return the name of the test-specific module instead of the *module-under-test*) in which you'd add a `<stylesheet src="…" />` to include your stylesheet (simplest way if the stylesheet is only to be used for tests, put it in a `public` subfolder next to the test-specific `gwt.xml` file).
See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideAutomaticResourceInclusion

Alternatively, using `CssResource` as you did, you might want to call [`StyleInjector.flush()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/StyleInjector.html#flush%28%29) just after your call to `ensureInjected()`.